# How can we automate a USSD application not using Selenium or QTP

Tags: automated-testing, eclipse

Architecture

- USSD platform > Which is written in Java and interact with ESME.
- USSD Application > Which is written in Java and interacts with Java application

Emulator > Generally a class which interacts with Platform and exchange xmls

So there is no web interface where we can use Eclipse tool.

The platform is an independent server. USSD Application runs on Tomcat and Emulator class runs as an independent Java application when both other are already running.

So what approach can be used to automate the flow of such applications?

Currently, we manually configure database tables, and generate a request using emulator class and gets output on the eclipse console.

How input can be automated and output can be verified??

Please help

Comment: Any specific reason for not using QTP?

Comment: QTP is not being used due to its closed platform reasons, we only use open source.